# Is a C*-correspondence just a Hilbert space you get from the Gelfand-Naimark theorem?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

A C*-correspondence over a C*-algebra $A$ is a (right) Hilbert $A$-module (<strike>so a Hilbert space</strike>) $H$ together with a faithful representation $A\rightarrow B(H)$. Am I right in understanding that a C*-correspondence is just a Hilbert space that you get from the Gelfand-Naimark theorem?

Just to know more, is it possible to have multiple C*-correspondences over a single C*-algebra? I think yes. I would be happy to see some examples. I am also interested in knowing about any literature where they consider a family of C*-correspondences for whatever purposes.

Comment: A GNS representation doesn’t have to be faithful. And a single representation can be a direct sum of multiple GNS representations. But it is certainly true that every nondegenerate representation of a $C^\ast$-algebra is a direct sum of GNS representations.

Comment: A $C^\ast$-algebra can, of course, have multiple non-equivalent faithful representations. Say, a faithful cyclic representation cannot be equivalent to a faithful non-cyclic one.

Comment: If $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra of dimension $\ge2$, a Hilbert $A$ module is not going to have a (compatible) structure of a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Aweygan Interesting. Can you direct me to a proof of it or type it as an answer? I will accept it

Comment: A Hilbert $A$-module is not a Hilbert space per se. You should check your definitions again!

Comment: Awygan and Just dropped in raised a good point. I was following the description in your question statement and assumed we are talking about a Hilbert space, but a Hilbert $A$-modules is not a Hilbert space. While it does have an inner product, the inner product does not take values in $\mathbb{C}$ but instead in $A$. Which definition do you actually want to use?

Comment: Also, I may be wrong about this, since I’ve only seen correspondences in the context of von Neumann algebras, but aren’t correspondences supposed to be over two algebras, one acting on the left, the other acting on the right…?

Comment: @DavidGao and Just dropped in, I have edited it, thanks! Also I am only thinking of a C*-correspondance which is a right Hilbert A-module. I should have mentioned that earlier. We can also think of A-bimodules

Comment: @Aweygan Can the inner product of the Hilbert space in the Gelfand-Naimark representation not be extended to make it a Hilbert A-module?

Comment: @AksharaPrasad GNS construction only provides a left action. If I recall correctly, once you also have a right action it is possible to induce an $A$-valued inner product from the scalar inner product and the right action (at least, that is true in the vNa case, please correct me if I’m wrong about this part), but I don’t believe that is possible with just the left action provided by the GNS construction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B$ be $C^*$-algebras. An $A$-$B$-$C^*$-correspondence consists of a right Hilbert $B$-module $\mathcal{E}$ together with a (non-degenerate) $*$-homomorphism
$$\pi: A \to \mathcal{L}_B(\mathcal{E}).$$
Thus, $A$-$\mathbb{C}$-correspondences correspond to (non-degenerate) $*$-representations of $A$ on Hilbert spaces. This motivates the notion of $C^*$-correspondences, as it is natural to replace Hilbert spaces by Hilbert modules (and sometimes this is really necessary, as the representation theory of $C^*$-algebras on Hilbert spaces is not always strong enough to capture relevant information).

The underlying idea here is simple: $\mathcal{E}$ has (by definition) a right $B$-action. The existence of the $*$-morphism $\pi$ means that $\mathcal{E}$ also carries a left $A$-action, namely
$$a.\xi :=\pi(a)\xi, \quad a \in A, \xi \in \mathcal{E}$$
that is compatible with the right $B$-module structure. In other words, an $A$-$B$-$C^*$-correspondence should be thought of some kind of $C^*$-algebraic version of the notion of $A$-$B$-bimodule. Note however the asymmetry that $\mathcal{E}$ does not come with an $A$-valued inner product.

Comment: It probably wasnt your intention, but reading this answer just made the connection between the various definitions of KK modules click in my mind!

Comment: @Opisthokont Not in my mind when writing the answer, but glad to help :)